# Need help understanding pointers, functions and 2D arrays

Tags: c, arrays, function

The following is a snippet of code that parses tokens and stores them. The code compiles and works.

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int storeTokens(char *src, char *delim, char **storage, size_t len) {
    int idx = 0;
    char str[100] = {0};
    char *token = NULL;
    char *saveptr = NULL;

    // copy string so we don't modify the source
    if (snprintf(str, sizeof(str), "%s", src) < 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    // Loop through string and parse out tokens
    token = strtok_r(str, delim, &saveptr);
    while ((token != NULL) && (idx < len)) {
        snprintf(storage[idx], sizeof(storage[idx]), "%s", token);
        strcpy(storage[idx++], token);
        token = strtok_r(NULL, delim, &saveptr);
    }

    // Print the tokens
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++) {
        printf("fun: %s\n", storage[i]);
    }

    return idx; // number of tokens found
}

int main() {
    int i = 0;

    char teststr[] = "This*is*my*string*.";
    char *storageptr[72];
    char storage[72][255];

    // Assign storage space to the pointers
    for (i = 0; i < 72; i++) {
        storageptr[i] = storage[i];
    }

    // Parse the tokens
    int numtokens = storeTokens(teststr, "*", storageptr, 72);

    // Print the tokens
    for (i = 0; i < numtokens; i++) {
        printf("storage: %s\n", storage[i]);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Output**

```
fun: This
fun: is
fun: my
fun: string
fun: .
storage: This
storage: is
storage: my
storage: string
storage: .
```

The function stores the string with the `char **storage` variable. The reason for this being a double pointer is so the function can be used on any storage regardless of the length.

My problem is passing the storage into the function. As you can see in `main`, I created `storageptr` to point to `storage` before passing it to the function.

This seems convoluted and unnecessary. Not to mention the time wasted looping and linking each string. However I can't figure out how to pass `storage` directly into the function without creating `storageptr`.

I've done reading such as [Passing an array of strings to a C function by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189461/passing-an-array-of-strings-to-a-c-function-by-reference), but nothing really clicks. I can't seem to figure out how to properly pass `storage` into the function.

Comment: I blogged about `char **` here: http://www.dima.to/blog/?p=478 Its just a list of strings, and its already a pointer so you pass it as is. But, I think what might be causing you problems is finding a distinction between a 2D array and pointers.

Comment: In your `storeTokens` function, `storage` is a pointer to a pointer. `storage[idx]` is a pointer. And doing `sizeof` on a pointer (like e.g. `sizeof(storage[idx])`) returns the size of the *pointer* and not what it points to. That is seems to work indicates that you're on a 64-bit system where pointers are 64 bits (8 bytes). Try using longer sub-strings than 8 characters and see it fail.

Comment: As for your problem, have you thought about *dynamic allocation*? Perhaps you should do some research about [`malloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc), [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) and [`free`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude due to the nature of where the code is being used, dynamic allocation isn't an option. As for the sizeof, I figured that was wrong. Thanks for pointing that out. I'll change it to strcpy since it's not the target of the topic.

Comment: @Alexandru the issue is I have `char storage[72][255]` and I'm looking to pass that to a function with `char **storage`. The issue I'm having is I can't understand how to pass the 2D array directly into the function without creating pointers to each element.

Comment: You can't pass a `char array[72][255]` directly to a `char **ptr`, they aren't compatible types. `array` is composed of 72*255 contiguous chars, without a single pointer **stored** anywhere. However, since ptr is a `char **`, the compiler expects `ptr[0]` to be a `char *`. What you'd need in that case, is a pointer to an array, as shown in the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a C99 or C11, having optional VLA support, compatible compiler you can pass directly the 2D array specifying dynamically the size of your array:

```
int storeTokens(char *src, char *delim, size_t len, size_t size, char storage[len][size]);
```

Call from main:

```
int numtokens = storeTokens(teststr, "*", 72, 255, storage);
```

If you have a C11 compiler to be sure that it supports VLA's (that are optional for C11) check the symbol **STDC_NO_VLA**, if it is defined the compiler **does not support VLA's**.

Comment: Wow, that works! I had no idea you could use the variables declared in the function within the function declaration itself. This is allows me to use any size array which was the intention of the double pointer. Is there anything further I should about that or is that basically the gist of it?

Comment: This is called VLA variable length array. I.e. see http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array. I forget to specify that in a C11 compiler the support for C11 is optional.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you *need* to keep the argument as a pointer to pointer (to `char`), then to be able to pass the array of arrays (of `char`) directly you need to change the function signature:

```
int storeTokens(char *src, char *delim, char (*storage)[255], size_t len)
//                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Now you can pass `storage` from the `main` function:

```
storeTokens(teststr, "*", storage, 72)
```

---

The problem is that while arrays can decay to a pointer to its first element, it's not "recursive".

If you have an array like yours

```
char storage[72][255];
```

then when it decays to a pointer to its first element it is `&storage[0]`, which is a pointer to an *array*. This secondary array will not decay, so passing `storage` will pass a pointer to an array (of type `char (*)[255]`).

If you *must* pass a `char **`, then the intermediate `storageptr` array is needed.